# Make CSS steps progress bar use full width of available space

Tags: css, progress-bar

I have the following steps progress bar:

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Register</li>
    <li class="active">Sync</li>
    <li>Activate</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<style>
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active:before {
  border-color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: green;
}

</style>
```

As each of the three steps have a width of 33.3%, the outer edges of the progress bar have a huge padding. I need to get rid of this extra space, to use all of the available space. How can I achieve this? Instead of specifyng an exact width %, and to avoid hard-coding the amount of steps, I'm thinking, something along the lines of:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you! I gave a specific flex value for each of the li elements.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background-color: tan;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.progressbar {
    counter-reset: step;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.progressbar li {
    flex: 1 1 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffe;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.progressbar li::before {
    counter-increment: step;
    content: counter(step);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    background-color: white;
}

.progressbar li::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    z-index: 10;
    left: -50%;
    top: 15px;
}

.progressbar li:first-child::after{
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active::before{
  border-color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active + li::after {
  background-color: green;
}


.progressbar2 {
    counter-reset: step;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.progressbar2 li {
    flex: 1 1 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffe;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.progressbar2 li::before {
    counter-increment: step;
    content: counter(step);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    background-color: white;
}

.progressbar2 li:first-child{
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.progressbar2 li:last-child{
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.progressbar2 li:first-child::after{
  content: none;
}

.progressbar2 li.active2 {
  color: green;
}

.progressbar2 li.active2::before{
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Register</li>
        <li class="active">Sync</li>
        <li>Activate</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <ul class="progressbar2">
        <li class="active2">Register</li>
        <li class="active2">Sync</li>
        <li>Activate</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ale, thank you for your message! The :after is for the line inbetween the numbers. Unfortunately your code didn't work. All it did was mess up this said line. I followed the guide of this CSS magician here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYevj6UGNWA. If you could help out, I would be most thankful!

Comment: Posted an update for you

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort @alechristopher, but unfortunately the progress bar still has the padding on the sides. I made a plunker here to be able to edit the code, if you would have the time and the will! https://plnkr.co/plunk/zjlSVp6sS7LkPKpz

Comment: What padding are you referring too? I added some colors so you can see theres no padding on the li element. I also added a second layout, to see if thats what you are actually going for ( if so you might need a different strategy for making the actual line in between the elements.